# Change session timeout for netbeans-embedded grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, netbeans, session-timeout

I'm running a grails 1.3.9 application in Netbeans 7.1.1 IDE, and would like to decrease the session  timeout for testing purposes. My prolem is I can't find a server.xml file under neither the NetBeansProjects nor the NetBeans folders. Is it located elsewhere or is it named differently ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also alter the build of the web.xml file with a groovy script '_Events.groovy' in the '/script' directory. You can use the 'eventWebXmlEnd' event to add your configuration:

```
import grails.util.Environment
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

eventWebXmlEnd = { String tmpfile ->

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(webXmlFile)

    if(Environment.getCurrent() == 'TEST' ) {

        root.appendNode {

             'session-config' { 'session-timeout' (120) }

        }
    }

    webXmlFile.text = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {

        mkp.declareNamespace("": "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee")

        mkp.yield(root)

    }
}
```

Comment: And does this require to run the install-template command previously ? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. The last part was missing.. No, this solution doesn't require to install the templates...

Comment: The application starts but tomcat doesn't recognize its context root once I added the script.

Answer (score 0):

The session timeout is handled in the web.xml.  You need to run grails install-templates which will give you a web.xml that you can manipulate.  See the [docs here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html).

You would add this to your web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this would affect the "production" war, I want that one to have the server's default timeout all the time. What I need is only the one I run in my test environmet to have a short timeout (and I don't want to micromanage it by changing the file's timeout everytime I generate the war).